# Ошибка после установки на Ubuntu ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist

Tags: база-данных, ubuntu, oracle, установка, oracle11g

*SQL*PLUS* выдаёт ошибку:

> ERROR:
>       ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
>       ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
>       Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
>       Process ID: 0
>       Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

При старте БД:

```
sudo service oracle-xe start
Starting Oracle Net Listener.
Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.
Failed to start Oracle Net Listener using /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr and Oracle Express Database using /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus.
```

Ставила по этой [инструкции](http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2014/03/18/installing-java-oracle-11g-r2-express-edition-and-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-64-bit/).
Но пропустила шаг:

```
sudo rm -rf /dev/shm
sudo mkdir /dev/shm
```

потому, что при простой замене имени каталога `/dev/shm` у меня пропал интернет. Просто так удалять системные файлы, боязно. Теперь не могу удалить `/dev/shm`, т.к. он занят.

Comment: Запустите БД - `echo startup | sqlplus / as sysdba`

Comment: Не совсем понял, как отключение от интернета повлияло на переименование `/dev/shm`? И там не переименование, а пересоздание, хотя и оно не нужно, достаточно перемотирование.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сообщение об ошибке:

> ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist

означает, что процесс (обычно Listener, `sqlplus`) не может подсоединиться к System Global Area (**SGA**).

В основном  это вызывают две причины:

1. SGA действительно не существует, так как инстанция БД не стартовала.
   Стартуйте инстанцию БД под пользователeм `oracle`:

   ```
   $ echo startup|sqlplus / as sysdba
   ```
2. *Shared memory segment Id* для подключения к SGA генерируется из значений переменных окружения: `$ORACLE_SID + $ORACLE_HOME`. Если эти значения не соответствуют тем, которые были использованы при запуске инстанции БД, то будет выше указанная ошибка, так как такого сегмента не существует. Проверьте переменные окружения:

   ```
   env | egrep -i "oracle_(sid|home)"
   ```

   Значения `$ORACLE_SID + $ORACLE_HOME`, которые были использованы при установке 
   хранятся в `/etc/oratab` и устанавливаются так:

   ```
   export ORACLE_SID=orcl; . oraenv
   ```

Например, если попытаться установить вручную и при этом ошибиться:

```
$ echo exit|sqlplus -l user/pass 

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

$ ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME/; test -d $ORACLE_HOME && echo "directory exists"
#                   ------^
directory exists
```

Всё хорошо, директория существует и `sqlplus` из неё будет вызываться, но незначащий слэш даст при подсчёте `shmid` другое значение:

```
$ echo exit|sqlplus -l user/pass

ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Спасибо, были оба пункта!