# При подключении к БД ошибка: cx_Oracle.OperationalError: ORA-01034: ORACLE not available ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, solaris, cx-oracle

Пытаюсь подключиться к БД через библиотеку cx_Oracle. Применяю следующий код:

```
import cx_Oracle

lib_dir_test = r"C:\Program Files\instantclient_11_2"
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=lib_dir_test)

host = 'host_ip'
user = 'name'
password = 'password'
port = 1521
db = 'name_db'
SID = 'sid_name'

dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, db)
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user, password, dsn)
```

либо:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("name/password@host_ip:1521/sid_name")
```

Выводится ошибка:

```
cx_Oracle.OperationalError: ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
SVR4 Error: 2: No such file or dirrectory
Идентификатор процесса: 0
Идентификатор сеанса: 0 Порядковый номер: 0
```

При этом PL/SQL Developer подключается к базе данных без ошибок.

Файл конфигурации клиента Oracle - TNSNAMES.ORA содержит:

```
...
name_db = 
(DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host_ip)(Port = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
        (SID = sid_name)
    )
)

...
```

---

Используется: Oracle 9i, Python 3.8
Операционная система на сервере - Solaris, клиент на Windows 7.
Более старые версии клиентов не цепляются с cx_Oracle.

Comment: Посмотрите, о причинах [этой ошибки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/848183/217579). Почему вы используете SID, а не имя сервиса?  Подозреваю, что у вас листенер неправильно сконфигурирован.

Comment: @0xdb, а разве в Oracle 9i уже был "service name"?

Comment: @MaxU Вроде да, [уже был](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/network.920/a96580/namingcf.htm).

Comment: @0xdb, автор вопроса утверждает `При этом PL/SQL Developer подключается к базе данных без ошибок.`  с использованием `(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = sid_name))` - похоже используется все-таки SID

Comment: Какие у вас версии (включая архитектуру / "битность") Oracle Client Software, Python и cx_Oracle ?

Comment: @MaxU Также возможно, что PL/SQL Developer подключается не используя tnsnames.ora, этого в вопросе не указано. Кроме того, эта ошибка может возникнуть только на сервере, что означает - клиент отработал нормально,  а у листенера с SID неувязка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Типичная ошибка непонимания, что:

`sid_name`, `db_name` и `service_name` - все три хоть и связаны между собой, но они не одно и тоже, и могут иметь различные значения.

Связь такая: инстанция монтирует и обслуживает одну из баз данных, и регистрирует для неё в прослушивателе один или несколько сервисов для подключения. Посмотрите их имена таким запросом:

```
select what, sys_context ('userenv', what) name 
from (select trim (column_value) what 
    from xmlTable ('"instance_name","db_name","service_name"'))
```

---

Вот здесь:

```
db = 'name_db'
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, db)
```

Будет создана строка подключения с именем БД, где ожидается SID ([третий аргумент](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/module.html#cx_Oracle.makedsn)). Но прослушиватель не отверг это имя - оно ему известно, то есть прослушиватель, скорее всего, сконфигурирован неверно:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER = (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
        (SID_NAME = db_name)
        (ORACLE_HOME = /path_to/db_home)
    ))
```

Такая попытка подключения:

```
import cx_Oracle as cxora

dsn = cxora.makedsn ('dbserver.domain.net', 1521, 'db_name')
conn = cxora.connect ("user", "pass", dsn)
```

будет безуспешной:

```
cx_Oracle.OperationalError: ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

---

PS

> либо
>
> ```
> connection = cx_Oracle.connect("name/password@host_ip:1521/sid_name")
> ```

Не верю. Здесь надо `service_name` вместо `sid_name`. Ошибка другая, посмотрите внимательней.

Comment: Пример идеального ответа. И по форме и по содержанию )

Comment: @0xdb - Большое спасибо за ответ, натолкнувший на правильные мысли... проблема решена, я не правильно указал sid_name и ещё что-то... =) Прошу прощения за то, что от меня долго не было обратной связи - на работе максимальный завал... Точнее по своим ошибкам отпишусь на выходных... Ещё раз огромное спасибо!

Comment: @PanChous Да всё в порядке. Если нет времени, то просто оставте короткий комментарий - _В цейтноте, проверю позже_ , и всё.